# Check if username is available and email verification

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with checking if the username exist. It works if it does exist. But if the username doesn't exist it just send  me to an empy page. It seems that it doesn't go to the next statement.

Here the code

```
<?php
if($_POST[username]  && $_POST[email] &&  isset($_POST[password])  && isset($_POST[password2])  && $_POST[password] == $_POST[password2])
{
    include ('*********'); /my connection to the database
    $username = $_POST[username];

            //check with the registred members
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM registredMembers WHERE username='$username'"; 
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $existing_users = mysql_num_rows($result2) or die(mysql_error());

            // check with the temporarly members, waiting to activate account
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM tempMembers WHERE username='$username'"; 
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $existing_users2 = mysql_num_rows($result3) or die(mysql_error());

    if($existing_users != 0 && $existing_users2 != 0) 
    {
        echo "<div id='msg'>Användarnamnet är upptaget</div>";
    }

    else 
    {   
        $confirmCode = md5(uniqid(rand()));
        $query = "INSERT INTO tempMembers VALUES ('$confirmCode', '$_POST[username]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]')";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        if($result)
        {
            $to = $_POST[email];
            $subject = utf8_decode("Här är din bekräftelselänk");
            $header = utf8_decode("Från Adib Haider (PHP-Projekt)");
            $message = "Din bekräftelselänk \r\n";
            $message.= "Klicka på länken för att aktivera ditt konto \r\n";
            $message.= "http://labb.vgy.se/~adibbinhar/blogg/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirmCode";
            $sentmail = mail($to, $subject, utf8_decode($message), $header);

            if($sentmail)
                echo "<div id='msg'>Aktiveringsmailet har skickat till din e-postadress</div>";
            else 
                echo "<div id='msg'>Aktiveringsmailet skickades inte</div>";
        }

        else
            echo "<div id='msg'>Testa igen</div>";
    }   
}

else
    echo "<div id='msg'>Prova igen</div>";
```

the text is on swedish hope you can live with that :P

Comment: Did you sanitize your input (POST) ?

Comment: Try to cast the types like:     $existing_users = (int)mysql_num_rows($result2) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: And you could also have only one $existing_users variable, there is no need for two ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/I went through your code and added a little protection from injections as well as hopefully fixing your problem.
Like Joachim said, when the mysql_num_rows didn't return anything, you die()  the script.

This is the code I whipped together, you need to check the tables are correct and like, as this was a real quick run through:

```
    <?php
    if($_POST['username']  && $_POST['email'] &&  isset($_POST['password'])  && isset($_POST['password2'])  && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2'])
    {
        include ('*********'); //my connection to the database
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        //check with the registred members
        $query1 = "SELECT * 
                     FROM registredMembers as users, 
                          tempMembers as temp
                     WHERE users.username = '$username' 
                        OR temp.username ='$username'";

        $check = mysql_query($query1, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($check) < 1)
        {
            $confirmCode = md5(uniqid(rand()));
            $query = "INSERT INTO tempMembers (`confirmCode`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$confirmCode', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

            if($result)
            {
                $to = $email;
                $subject = utf8_decode("Här är din bekräftelselänk");
                $header = utf8_decode("Från Adib Haider (PHP-Projekt)");
                $message = "Din bekräftelselänk \r\n";
                $message.= "Klicka på länken för att aktivera ditt konto \r\n";
                $message.= "http://labb.vgy.se/~adibbinhar/blogg/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirmCode";
                $sentmail = mail($to, $subject, utf8_decode($message), $header);

                if($sentmail)
                {
                    echo "<div id='msg'>Aktiveringsmailet har skickat till din e-postadress</div>";
                }
                else
                { 
                    echo "<div id='msg'>Aktiveringsmailet skickades inte</div>";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                echo "<div id='msg'>Testa igen</div>";
            }
        }

        else
        {
            echo "<div id='msg'>Användarnamnet är upptaget</div>";
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div id='msg'>Prova igen</div>";
    }
```

Comment: it worked! thanks!

but what does your code mean? 
<code>mysql_real_escape_string

and the query
     <code> $query1 = "SELECT * 
                     FROM registredMembers as users, 
                          tempMembers as temp
                     WHERE users.username = '$username' 
                        OR temp.username ='$username'";</code>

Comment: but it dosn't check from the tempMembers database only from registredMembers

Comment: It should check from both tables and it will look in both takes for anyone with the given username :). Also the "<a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php">mysql_real_escape_string()</a>" sanitized the data to make is ready to be inserted into the database. Helps prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 2):

Add the "activated" column to your mysql:

**MYSQL**

```
ID | USERNAME | [...] FIELDS [...] | ACTIVATED
1  | Foo      | [...] FIELDS [...] | 1
```

**PHP**

```
[...]
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM registredMembers WHERE username='. mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['activated'] == 1) {
       // User activated
    } else {
       // Send activation email
    }
}
```

Not tested, but can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check that tempMembers actually exists, and that you don't have any unique constraints in the database that prevent the insert from succeeding when you try with a username or email that already exists in the database.

if the INSERT mysql_query returns 0 as a result, you die with mysql_error(), you can't even get to the else clause since $result just can't be 0.

(and yes, I hope you sanitized your inputs before entering this function :-)

Comment: the tempMembers base exists, but what is sanitize and how do i do it?

Comment: Sanitizing is basically seeing to that there are no characters in the input that will cause your page to act in the wrong way. For example, if you try to register with a username or email that contains a ' character, you'll end up getting SQL errors. That's why MrE is using mysql_real_escape_string to replace all characters mysql is sensitive to before using them in the SQL string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here lies in your if statement.

```
if($existing_users != 0 && $existing_users2 != 0)
```

Should be

```
if($existing_users != 0 || $existing_users2 != 0)
```

I don't know how your system works, but I guess that a username that exists in the `tempMembers` table doesn't necessarily exist in the `registredMembers` table.

You want the if statement to say: If the user exists in either the `tempMembers` table or `registeredMembers` table.

**Edit**:

I guess the empty page you get is a page that will display errors if you active them.

Try adding this at the top of your php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: it didn't help but the error message said username was undefined